# c# MultipartFormDataContent Add methods (how to properly add a file)

Tags: c#, file-upload, httpclient, addition, multipartform-data

I'm using the MultipartFormDataContent to upload a file to a rest API. This is working well, but my questions focuses on the proper way to use the Add(...) method to include the file content. Currently I am doing such:

```
string fileName = "foobar.txt";
MultipartFormDataContent formContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
ByteArrayContent byteArray = ...;
formContent.Add(byteArray, "file", fileName);
...
```

again, this works - I am trying to understand the parameters to the Add(...) method. In the MSDN documentation at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.multipartformdatacontent(v=vs.118).aspx

it has two add methods:

1. **Add(HttpContent, String)**
2. **Add(HttpContent, String, String)**

however neither has a description listed, and when drilling into the methods themselves, the parameters are only described (again without descriptions) as:

1. HttpContent content, string name
2. HttpContent content, string name, string fileName

*so, my specific questions in this context are:*

- What is the '**name**' parameter? (the one I'm setting as "file")?
- Does this need to be the literal string "file" or can it be something else?
- How is it used?

Comment: I don't use Add at all.  See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42212406/how-to-send-a-file-and-form-data-with-httpclient-in-c-sharp/42212590#42212590

Comment: @Fran thank you. It appears you are using a similar pattern where (in the same array as your surveyId) you add: (1) the byteArrayContent, (2) the literal string **"file"**, (3) andthe file name. My question still stands about this middle parameter: must it be the literal string "file" if a file is being uploaded? what else is this parameter used for?

Comment: It is written into the content disposition header.  it looks like you can leave it off for a file upload.  name looks like it corresponds to the input name. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

Comment: @Fran - looks good, thank you for figuring this out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is written into the content disposition header. it looks like you can leave it off for a file upload. name looks like it corresponds to the input name.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

Answer (score 5):

As per the method with three parameters, following's a brief description for each param.

```
public void Add(HttpContent content, string name, string fileName);
```

**content** - content that needs to be sent (Ex: array, file).

**name** - Name for that content. This is essential if the web API has to search for a specific name.

**filename** - The name which'll be added to the content-disposition header of the message. This will be used by the web API to save the file.